CORS preflight and request works, but browser console replay request fails
I'm not new to CORS in the world of server admin but in the browser (Chrome 131, Windows) I am not as familiar.
I use a web app at tools.siteground.com. There is a button which when clicked uses fetch() to submit a PUT request to a separate domain, xyz.siteground.biz. When clicking the button the CORS request works, and in devtools' network inspector we see the preflight and PUT requests both succeed with 200 status.
I want to replay this request in the browser on demand.
If I right-click the PUT request, I can "Copy as fetch" and paste it into the console. Since the original request was also a fetch() request, and I am pasting and running the same request in the console for the same document, it should operate exactly as if the page executed the request a second time. But, it fails.
When reviewing the network inspector we see a second preflight request, which succeeds, followed by the PUT request initiated in the console, which fails due to CORS error. The only notable difference from the prior, page-initiated, PUT request is the lack of any set cookies.
When reviewing the console error output, we see that a particular response header in the preflight response is considered problematic given that the request uses the header credentials:include
Q1: Why is there a second preflight request?
Q2: What exactly is going on here?
Q3: Is there any way to make it work in the browser or the only option is curl or similar?
EDIT: To whoever marked this question a duplicate of CORS: Cannot use wildcard in Access-Control-Allow-Origin when credentials flag is true
This is not the same issue. That question is a server-side question, this one is not. I understand that the error I am seeing in the client can be fixed on the server side. This question is specifically regarding why duplicating a working fetch request in the browser console fails with this particular error. If the answer to that question was simply that the copy/paste operation erroneously included the credentials:include header, then fine--it must be a browser bug. But! Without that header in the request, the server issues a 401 response. This is because the authorization cookies are passed with the request only when the credentials:include header is set. So the question remains, how do you duplicate the initial, working, fetch() request in the console?



Seems like the response contains a Set-Cookie header which the browser interprets as requiring credentials:include but the server's CORS configuration doesn't actually allow it. Simply remove that option from your fetch() request

the issue is that the response header Access-Control-Allow-Origin is * with credentials: include in the request - the error is telling you that is not allowed

@Phil removing credentials: include results in a 401 (unauthorized) response. The headers set with my fetch() necessarily match those from the original (successful) request, otherwise they wouldn't be copied from it. Can't be a server issue, there is something the browser is doing differently in the execution context of the console.

@Bravo Well obviously the fetch was not allowed or else it would not have thrown an error; I'm trying to sort out why it works in the document context but not in the console. The fetch call should be identical in both cases, unless I'm mistaken.

If you compare the response headers received by the app-generated OPTIONS request vs the console generated one are they the same?

can we see both cases in your question? clearly the server isn't responding correctly in one case vs the other

"the server issues a 401 response"... maybe the bearer token you're trying to re-use has expired or was single-use. You typically wouldn't need a cookie and an Authorization header. In any case, you should be able to check the working fetch() code. I'd hazard a guess that it does not use credentials: include
